# Set View Controller for TabBarController index, depending on value

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a user-specific value in my firebase database.
To simplify it either a or b. I'm using a TabBarController in my app:
If the value is a, the ViewController(which is embedded in a navigation controller) for index 0 should be different than if it's value b.
Tab Bar -> NavigationController (index 0) -> either ViewController A or B

Can I somehow set this in a TabBarController class, Navigation Controller class or how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct config like what you might think , but if you get the value before you show the tabBar you can do this inside the custom class of it

```
class CustomTab:UITabBarController {

   override func awakeFromNib() {
     super.awakeFromNib()

    let nav = self.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController

     if a {
       let vcA = ///
       nav.viewControllers = [vcA]
      }
     else {
       let vcB = ///
       nav.viewControllers = [vcB]
     }
  }
}
```